# Spring mvc tags form save object

Tags: java, spring

i have problem with save field type object(kategoria) with jsp

```
<form:form id="temat" method="POST" modelAttribute="temat" action="nowyTemat" >
    <p>Wprowadz tytul tematu:</p>
     <form:input id="tytul" path="tytul" type="text"  maxlength="255" />
    <p>Wprowadz tekst:</p>
    <form:textarea id="tresc" path="tresc" rows="9" cols="40" /></br>
    </br>
    <form:select path="kategoria"
        items="${kategorie}"
        itemLabel="nazwa"
        itemValue="id"
    />
        <br/></br>
        <input type="submit" value="Dodaj"/>
</form:form>
```

other fields tytul and tresc save good becouse have type field String my field kategoria in entity have OBJECT

```
@Entity
@Table(name="temat")

public class Temat {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private int id;
private Date data;
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="kategoria")
private Kategoria kategoria;

private String tytul;
@Lob
private String tresc;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="uzytkownik")
private Uzytkownik uzytkownik;
@OneToMany(mappedBy="temat", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
@OrderBy("data ASC")
private Set<Wpis> wpisy;
```

how i can save this field ?

Answer (score 1):

I think that is because your server side cannot bind to `kategoria` so. I will propose you to add in your jsp file the id of `kategoria` and replace your form:select with :

```
 <form:select path="kategoria.id"
        items="${kategorie}"
        itemLabel="nazwa"
        itemValue="id"
    />
```